# How to call UseBasePath() in Blazor with .NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

There a tons of articles how to call UseBasePath() in a Blazor server side application - but unfortunately all describe how to do it in Startup() or Configure() up to .NET Core 5.
With .NET Core 6, a "new minimal hosting model" was introduced, so that Startup.cs and Program.cs no longer exist in the old way, nor the Configure() method.
Like mentioned e.g. in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

How can I call UseBasePath() in the new, minimal Program.cs when there only are few lines of code left?
Not that I wouldn't appreciate this improvement, but for a ASP.NET newbie like me it is getting very difficult here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
app.UsePathBase("/app");
```

Or did I miss the question?

Comment: That's the problem. In .NET Core 5 there has been a method Configure() where app has been of type IApplicationBuilder and app.UseBasePath() was possible (at least as far as I understand this, as I already said, I'm not very familiar with configuring Blazor).
But in .NET Core 6, in the "new" program.cs, app is of type WebApplication:

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
WebApplication app = builder.Build();

IMHO, the IApplicationBuilder is hidden somewhere within the builder and should be configured before calling builder.Build(), but I've got no idea.

Comment: @HansHeinz  `UseBasePath()` is now `UsePathBase()`. It should probably be early in the `app.Use<Stuff>()` lineup.

Comment: Aaaarrrgghhh... I didn't see this little difference...
Thank you guys!